# how to use visual studio debugging sub process?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, debugging, visual-c++

I want to debugging a process B which started by process A,Bug when I attched process B,I can`t break on main function. Is there a way auto break when process B started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately no way with visual-studio. at first and main - this debugger can not debug several processes at once. it can debug only one process. if you debug process *A* and it started process *B* - this debugger simply can not debug new process *B*.

in general when we debug process *A* - exist `DebugPort` object attached to process. ( `EPROCESS.DebugPort` ) also in `EPROCESS` object exist `NoDebugInherit` flag. when process *A* start new process *B* - system do next (pseudo code):

```
if (Process->DebugPort && !Process->NoDebugInherit) 
    AttachDebugPortToNewProcess(Process->DebugPort);
```

if *A* under debugger and `NoDebugInherit` flag not set - new process *B* also attached to the same `DebugPort` (same debugger).

how is `NoDebugInherit` is set ?

if we start process via `CreateProcess` api - if we set [`DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684863(v=vs.85).aspx) the `NoDebugInherit` set to true. if we use [`DEBUG_PROCESS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684863(v=vs.85).aspx) **without** [`DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684863(v=vs.85).aspx) - `NoDebugInherit` set to false - as result all child processes created by the new process will be also debugged.

if we attach to already running process via `DebugActiveProcess` `NoDebugInherit` set to true. as result if this process start new process - it will be not debugged.

and we can query and set this `NoDebugInherit` via `NtQueryInformationProcess` and `NtSetInformationProcess` with `ProcessDebugFlags` *`PROCESSINFOCLASS`* (it declared in *ntddk.h*). with this we can at any time query and change `ProcessDebugFlags` by next code:

```
// from WRK\WRK-v1.2\public\sdk\inc\ntpsapi.h  

//
// Define process debug flags
//
#define PROCESS_DEBUG_INHERIT 0x00000001

NTSTATUS SetDebugInherit(HANDLE hProcess, BOOLEAN bInherit)
{
    ULONG DebugFlags;

    // hProcess must have PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION access
    NTSTATUS status = NtQueryInformationProcess(hProcess, ProcessDebugFlags, &DebugFlags, sizeof(DebugFlags), 0);

    if (0 <= status)
    {
        bInherit ? DebugFlags |= PROCESS_DEBUG_INHERIT : DebugFlags &= ~PROCESS_DEBUG_INHERIT;

        // hProcess must have PROCESS_SET_INFORMATION access
        status = NtSetInformationProcess(hProcess, ProcessDebugFlags, &DebugFlags, sizeof(DebugFlags));
    }

    return status;
}
```

if return back to *MSVS* or *WinDbg* - it always start new process with [`DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684863(v=vs.85).aspx) . even if we yourself set `NoDebugInherit` to false and start new process - anyway new process will be not debugged and even not run if we use *MSVS*. in case *WinDbg* try formal debug 2 (and more) processes at once but can not do this too. you need have better debugger which designed to debug multiple processes in concurrent.

another possibility set break-point in `CreateProcessInternalW` in process *A* and after it hit - set break-point to `NtResumeThread` (this must be temporary breakpoint - after `CreateProcessInternalW` hit only). when `NtResumeThread` hit - new process `B` is started already (in suspended state). at this point you can run new instance of *MSVS* or *WinDbg* and attach to it. however here also can be problems, because most debuggers (*MSVS* and *WinDbg*) use `DebugActiveProcess`. this api after call `NtDebugActiveProcess` which is need and enough for begin debug process, by some reason create (`DbgUiIssueRemoteBreakin`) new thread in target process (`DbgUiRemoteBreakin`). as result new process begin executed on this thread. in xp this leads to process initialization fail. in modern windows - this is in general worked, but anyway can affect process execution - main process thread became not first in process.

if *B* is your process - so you can modify it code, you always can do next in point, where you want attach/break debugger:

```
while (!IsDebuggerPresent()) Sleep(1000);
__debugbreak();
```

or if you can show gui:

```
WCHAR sz[64];
swprintf(sz, L"attact to %u(0x%x)\n", GetCurrentProcessId(), GetCurrentProcessId());
while (!IsDebuggerPresent()) MessageBoxW(0,0,sz, MB_ICONINFORMATION);
__debugbreak();
```

Comment: Thank you verymuch,I use messagebox ways^_^

Answer (score 1):

When you manually attach to process B, it must have already run for some time.

With the plugin "[Microsoft Child Process Debugging Power Tool](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vsdbgplat.MicrosoftChildProcessDebuggingPowerTool)", VS can automatically attach to child processes when they start, and you can break at the first statement in `main()`.